# Why is a weak pointer to an MVar finalized, even though the MVar is still accessible?

Tags: haskell, weak-references

I'm seeing a problem mixing MVar and Weak: even though the MVar is still accessible from a function's scope (and the main thread is blocking on it), the Weak thinks it should be finalised. This behaviour only seems to happen when compiled with optimisations enabled.

Platform: 64-bit Linux

Reproduced with GHC versions: 6.10.4, 6.12.3, 7.0.4, 7.2.2, 7.4.1

```
module Main (main) where

import           Control.Concurrent
import           Control.Monad (forever, forM_)
import           Data.IORef
import           System.Mem
import           System.Mem.Weak

dispatchPendingCalls :: IORef [Weak (MVar ())] -> IO ()
dispatchPendingCalls ref = forever $ do
    threadDelay 100000

    pending <- atomicModifyIORef ref (\p -> ([], p))
    forM_ pending (\weak -> do
        maybeMVar <- deRefWeak weak
        case maybeMVar of
            Just mvar -> putMVar mvar ()
            Nothing -> putStrLn "dispatchPendingCalls: weak mvar is Nothing")

call :: IORef [Weak (MVar ())] -> IO ()
call ref = do
    mvar <- newEmptyMVar
    weak <- mkWeakPtr mvar (Just (putStrLn "call: finalising weak"))

    putStrLn "call: about to insert weak into list"
    atomicModifyIORef ref (\p -> (weak : p, ()))
    putStrLn "call: inserted weak into list"
    performGC
    takeMVar mvar
    putStrLn "call: took from mvar"

main :: IO ()
main = do
    pendingCalls <- newIORef []
    _ <- forkIO (dispatchPendingCalls pendingCalls)
    call pendingCalls
```

Expected output:

```
$ ghc --make WeakMvar.hs
$ ./WeakMvar
call: about to insert weak into list
call: inserted weak into list
call: took from mvar
$
```

Actual output:

```
$ ghc --make -O2 WeakMvar.hs
$ ./WeakMvar
call: about to insert weak into list
call: inserted weak into list
call: finalizing weak
dispatchPendingCalls: weak mvar is Nothing
(never exits)
```

Why is this happening? If I'm reading the `System.Mem.Weak` docs correctly, then the `takeMVar mvar` line ought to be keeping the mvar alive, and thus keeping its weak pointer valid. Instead, the weak pointer thinks the MVar has become unreachable *before* the call to `takeMVar` returns.

Comment: FYI: He submitted a bug report http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/6130
According to this, it should be fixed in GHC 7.6.1

Answer (score 1):

Try catching `BlockedIndefinitelyOnMVar` (which is handled by default IIR, so you won't see it) in your `takeMVar` in `call` . I guess using `Weak` keeps the GC from noticing your reference to the `MVar` in `dispatchPendingCalls`, so it gets garbage collected?

Comment: Using `catch (takeMVar mvar) (\BlockedIndefinitelyOnMVar -> putStrLn "blocked")` doesn't change the behavior. Besides, the GC shouldn't be garbage-collecting the mvar because `takeMVar` should be keeping it alive.

Comment: not sure what's going on, but the runtime will most certainly garbage collect a thread that is blocked indefinitely on an MVar with `takeMVar`, when all the other references disappear or are also blocked.

Answer (score 1):

This is almost certainly because GHC's optimizations tend to remove the data structures to which finalizers are attached, causing the finalizer to run too early.  That is, the finalizer is referencing the `MVar` data constructor instead of the underlying `MVar#`.  The [current docs](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/System-Mem-Weak.html) have some warnings about this.  If I use `Control.Concurrent.MVar.mkWeakMVar`, I see the expected output (with ghc-7.6.3).